# How to check which image is the source image of a button and change it every time the button is clicked in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What I am trying to do is, change the source image every time I hit the button. Suppose if the source image now is 'a' and when I press the button I want this to be 'b' and when I press it again I want it to be changed back to 'a' again.

I have this code to change the image once, but I am not able to check the current source image and hence I am not able to change it back to the previous one.

Note: I am using `FloatingActionButton`

```
        override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.fbDashboard.setOnClickListener {

            fb_dashboard.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_grid_view)
        }
        return binding.root
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just store the current state yourself? Also please tag the question as `android`, this is not directly / only related to Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

You could set the *tag* of the view to be the image resource id that's currently being displayed, and then use the current value of the tag to choose the next image to display:

```
val imageId = when (binding.fbDashboard.tag) {
    R.drawable.foo -> R.drawable.bar
    R.drawable.bar -> R.drawable.baz
    ...
    else -> R.drawable.foo
}

binding.fbDashboard.setImageResource(imageId)
binding.fbDashboard.tag = imageId
```